# Is there a design pattern for accessing concrete types in an IEnumerable<IFoo>?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, builder, factory-pattern

I am trying to apply a creation pattern to the following business domain. I am not sure if it is the right solution but I have been looking at the factory and builder pattern but I might be trying to apply the wrong pattern. Here is the following domain:

- Technical Specifications

  - Visual Specs

    - Field of View (String)
    - Resolution (String)
  - Audio Specs

    - Frequency Range (String)
    - Microphone (boolean)

So above I have a business objects of technical specifications, I am just showing an example of two but they could be up to N objects. This holds true for the properties of the technical specifications, there could up to N properties for each specification.

I am running into roadblocks trying to code this in an abstract way using the patterns mentioned above if I want to return back the properties of the technical specifications. I am forced to cast them, any advice on a pattern that would be applicable in this case?

Here is some code sample of what I am trying to do, please see below. In the main function I can build my specification objects but if I want to access the concrete properties of the Specification Object without casting. I hope this clarify some things.

Main Function:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TechnicalSpecificationBuilder visual = new VisualSpecificationBuilder();
            TechnicalSpecificationBuilder audio = new AuditorySpecificationBuilder();

            //TODO, how do I get acces to properties without Casting?
            Specification visualSpec = visual.CreateSpecification();
            Specification audiotSpec = audio.CreateSpecification();            
        }
    }
```

Abstract Tech Spec Builder:

```
public abstract class TechnicalSpecificationBuilder
    {

        public Specification CreateSpecification()
        {
            return BuildSpecification();
        }

        protected abstract Specification BuildSpecification();       
    }
```

Visual Tech Spec Builder:

```
 public class VisualSpecificationBuilder : TechnicalSpecificationBuilder
    {      
        protected override Specification BuildSpecification()
        {
            // TODO: Implement this method
            return new VisualSpecification();
        }
    }
```

Abstract Specification:

```
public abstract class Specification
    {

    }
```

Visual Specification:

```
public class VisualSpecification : Specification
    {
        public string FieldOfView { get; set; }
        public bool IsBinocularVisionCapable { get; set; }
        public bool IsHeadTrackingCapable { get; set; }
        public bool IsEyeTrackingCapable { get; set; }
        public string Resolution { get; set; }       
    }
```

Comment: You're going to have to cast unless you use `dynamic`.

Comment: Can you explain how to use dynamic?

Comment: @user1329436 https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+dynamic

Comment: I've tried to clarify your title, does it say what you meant?

Comment: If you want to do something non-generic with a generic interface you are going to have a problem. You can intentionally stab in the dark with the `dynamic` keyword but that should be reserved for situations where can't know, rather than can't be bothered to know. You need to defined an interface for a property.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use dynamic.  You still need to know which of the items have what methods, it's just that it doesn't matter until runtime.  That doesn't solve anything for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick - use a generic base class for the builder classes and make the concrete specification subclass a type parameter.

```
public abstract class TechnicalSpecificationBuilder<TSpecification>
   where TSpecification : Specification
{
   public TSpecification CreateSpecification()
   {
      return this.BuildSpecification();
   }

   protected abstract TSpecification BuildSpecification();       
}

public class VisualSpecificationBuilder : TechnicalSpecificationBuilder<VisualSpecification>
{      
   protected override VisualSpecification BuildSpecification()
   {
      return new VisualSpecification();
   }
}
```

I also suggest to think about using an interface `ISpecification` instead or together with you base class `Specification` - this could help if you reach a point where a concrete specification class can not derive from you base class for whatever reasons.